# Why cannot we cannot call a method of a destination activity in Android programming?

Tags: android, ios, android-activity, viewcontroller

I am studying both iOS and Android programming, and I found a difference between them.

In iOS programming, we can send a message to a destination view controller to setup it, but in Android programming, it seems that they doesn't provide even a reference to an activity. Although we can pass some extra information to an destination activity by putting it in Intent, it is not easy to pass a complex object.

I wonder why in Android programming we cannot call a method of a destination activity.

Comment: because they work differently? You'll have to ask the designers of Android/Java/iOS/Cocoa for that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was similarly surprised when going from iOS to Android development and here is what I found.

In Android, each activity is considered a stand alone unit. It is up to that activity to retrieve information from a data source matching the primitive parameters it was given. In fact, much of Android development is about creating these stand alone units of work that either display information, handle events, provide data to third-parties, etc.

Objective-C follows the more traditional method of moving from view to view. It is up to the developer of the receiving message from an external application to know which controller's view to display.